# Pointing one column to a column in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a large table with around half a million rows which is taking a toll on the shared hosting server. I am suppose to break down this large table into 3-4 smaller tables as we have no other option in shared hosting environment. While breaking down, I will keep that large table as it is and will take out only a specific column which contains large amount of text and split it into smaller tables.
What I am looking for now is a solution wherein I have to do minimum changes to the PHP code and the table can be split into several ones as follows:

main_table

```
id | column1 | column2 | column3_just_pointer
```

smaller_table_1

```
id | main_table_id | column3
```

smaller_table_2

```
id | main_table_id | column3
```

smaller_table_3

```
id | main_table_id | column3
```

If MySQL has something like pointer that can point to column3 in smaller table on executing a select command: select id, column3_just_pointer from main_table, I can split the tables in above mentioned fashion and the front end PHP code does not need to be edited at all.
I hope I sounded clear. Does any one here have any idea as to if and how this can be achieved? Thank you for your time...

Please Note: views cannot be used as it will prevent me from creating multiple smaller tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up totally partitioning the tables horizontally with names like smaller_table_1,smaller_table_2,etc and keeping a record of the starting and ending ids of each table in a separate table say 'main_table'. New data is added only to the last table and when a table crosses 40000 rows, my application automatically creates a new table smaller_table_n and put the information of that new table into main_table.

I had asked this question in March and till now - July, this setup as worked flawlessly in 3 of my websites and all my 3 hosts too are happy about the sites not taking up more resources on their server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing vertical partitioning, you can create a view that 'merges' all tables involved, so application doesn't have to know about underlying tables at all. 
For instance,

```
TABLE main_table(id -PK, column list);
TABLE detail1 (main_id - PK,FK to main_table, column list);
TABLE detail2 (main_id - PK,FK to main_table, column list);

CREATE VIEW main_view AS
SELECT a.id, [columns from main_table], [columns from detail1, detail2, etc]
FROM maint_table a
LEFT JOIN detail1 b ON (b.main_id = a.id)
LEFT JOIN detail2 c ON (c.main_id = a.id)
```

Now all application `select`s can be done against `main_view`.

Comment: But if I use views the problem is that the column that I have taken out of the main table cannot be split into multiple tables. I can just create smaller_table_1 and put all the half a million rows of that particular in that one table... Thank you for your reply...